# Could ancient Egyptians have done origami with papyrus?

Tags: ancient-egypt

Ancient Egyptians used papyrus as writing stationery. However, could one use papyrus for origami?

I couldn't find any resources for research...

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The papyrus is not [isotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy), is [anisotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropy). It can be imagined as a set of [elastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(physics)) thin sticks all fixed in one orientation by [plastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticity_(physics)) mass. It can be easily folded in one direction and is elastic and springy in the perpendicular one. So, you can do some sort of origami, especially with a wet sheet of papyrus. But its rules will be much different from those of the Japanese one and much more complicated. For example, large and small sheets will behave themselves absolutely differently.

When Egyptians wanted to make papyrus more or less isotropic, they put two layers of it, crossing the threads by right angles. That construct, though, according to my own experiments, is absolutely non-pliable. It is elastic (springy) in all directions.

But kites **could** be made of papyrus. But weren't....

Comment: There is in fact a subset of Japanese origami that is folded wet

Comment: Can you explain what isotropic means in this context, and why it is important for origami, please?

Comment: Basically, it has a grain.  It folds/cracks easily in one directly, not so easily in any other.

Comment: @ThomasFrancois  you are welcome :-)

Comment: @Gangnus the #10 noun sense of "grain" in WordNet is "the direction, texture, or pattern of fibers found in wood or leather or stone or in a woven fabric."

Comment: @StevenBurnap It is exactly what anisotropy means. I have added the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

No.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus):

> Codices were an improvement on the papyrus scroll, as the *papyrus was not pliable enough to fold without cracking* and a long roll, or scroll, was required to create large-volume texts.

Comment: Not everyone seems to agree with wikipedia on that [point](http://www.britishorigami.info/academic/lister/papyrus.php).

Comment: Interesting.  I guess there's one way to [find out](https://www.lib.umich.edu/papyrus_making/slides.html)